# VB.net Printing text from a multiline textbox and several datagridviews after that

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview, textbox, multiline

I am trying to print a multiline textbox and several different datagridviews after that.  I hope some of the kind souls here would be able to help me.

So far, it works well when there is only one page from the datagridview, after that the last page of the text gets repeated.

Like so:

[All Fine for Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unof5.jpg)
[Problems afoot for every other page after that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXTA7.jpg)

To all who are about to read my code-mess, you have my utmost thanks.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
Dim mRow As Integer = 0
Dim newpage As Boolean = True
Dim page As Integer = 0
Dim tablepage As Integer = 0
Dim content1 As String
Dim numChars As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

    mRow = 0
    newpage = True
    page = 0
    tablepage = 0
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

Dim numLines As Integer

    '1 Page
    'TEXT
    If page = 0 Then

        content1 = TextBox6.Text & vbLf & TextBox7.Text & vbLf & TextBox8.Text

            Dim stringForPage As String
            Dim strFormat As New StringFormat()
            Dim PrintFont As Font
            PrintFont = TextBox6.Font
            Dim rectDraw As New RectangleF(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height)
            Dim sizeMeasure As New SizeF(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height - PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics))
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.Word
            e.Graphics.MeasureString(content1, PrintFont, sizeMeasure, strFormat, numChars, numLines)
            stringForPage = content1.Substring(0, numChars)
            Dim rectDraw1 As New RectangleF(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics) * numLines)

            e.Graphics.DrawString(stringForPage, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, rectDraw1, strFormat)

        If numChars < content1.Length Then
            content1 = content1.Substring(numChars)
            e.HasMorePages = True
            page += 1

        Else
            e.HasMorePages = False
            'End If


            'DATAGRIDVIEW
            If tablepage > 0 Then
            With TableDataGridView
                Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
                fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
                Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top '

                Do While mRow < .RowCount

                    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                    Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                    Dim h As Single = 0
                    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                        Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                        If (newpage) Then
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                        Else
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                        End If
                        x += rc.Width
                        h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)

                    Next
                    newpage = False
                    y += h
                    mRow += 1

                    If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then ' 800 Then '

                        e.HasMorePages = True
                        newpage = True
                        mRow -= 1
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Loop

            End With

        Else

            'DATAGRIDVIEW < 2 page

            With TableDataGridView
                        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
                        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                        fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
                        Dim y As Single = 20 + rectDraw1.Bottom 'e.MarginBounds.Top '


                        Do While mRow < .RowCount

                            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                            Dim h As Single = 0
                            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                                If (newpage) Then
                                    e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                                Else
                                    e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                                End If
                                x += rc.Width
                                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)

                            Next
                            newpage = False
                            y += h
                            mRow += 1

                            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then '800 Then '

                                e.HasMorePages = True
                                newpage = True
                                mRow -= 1
                                tablepage += 1
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        Loop

                    End With
                End If

            End If

        'TEXT
        'More than 1 Page
    ElseIf page > 0 Then

        Dim stringForPage As String
            Dim strFormat As New StringFormat()
            Dim PrintFont As Font
            PrintFont = TextBox6.Font
            Dim rectDraw As New RectangleF(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height)
            Dim sizeMeasure As New SizeF(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height - PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics))
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.Word
            e.Graphics.MeasureString(content1, PrintFont, sizeMeasure, strFormat, numChars, numLines)
            stringForPage = content1.Substring(0, numChars)

            Dim rectDraw1 As New RectangleF(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, PrintFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics) * numLines)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(stringForPage, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, rectDraw1, strFormat)

            If numChars < content1.Length Then
                content1 = content1.Substring(numChars)
                e.HasMorePages = True
                page += 1
            Else
            e.HasMorePages = False

            'DATAGRIDVIEW
            If tablepage > 0 Then
                With TableDataGridView
                    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
                    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
                    Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top '

                    Do While mRow < .RowCount

                        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                        Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                        Dim h As Single = 0
                        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                            Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                            If (newpage) Then
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                            Else
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                            End If
                            x += rc.Width
                            h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)

                        Next
                        newpage = False
                        y += h
                        mRow += 1

                        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then ' 800 Then '

                            e.HasMorePages = True
                            newpage = True
                            mRow -= 1
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Loop

                End With

            Else

                'DATAGRIDVIEW < 2 page

                With TableDataGridView
                    Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
                    fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                    fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
                    Dim y As Single = 20 + rectDraw1.Bottom 'e.MarginBounds.Top '


                    Do While mRow < .RowCount

                        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
                        Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
                        Dim h As Single = 0
                        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                            Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                            If (newpage) Then
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                            Else
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(TableDataGridView.Rows(cell.RowIndex - 1).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                            End If
                            x += rc.Width
                            h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)

                        Next
                        newpage = False
                        y += h
                        mRow += 1

                        If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then '800 Then '

                            e.HasMorePages = True
                            newpage = True
                            mRow -= 1
                            tablepage += 1
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Loop

                End With
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem a bit yourself, no one is going to go through all that and do the work for you.

Comment: Thank you - I will keep hammering at it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the same code over and over why not do something like

```
Static Pos AS Integer

For I = Pos To TableDataGridView.Rows.Count

 'Do your graphics work here using TableDataGridView.Rows(i)

  If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
     Pos+=i
     e.hasmorepages = true
     Exit For
  end if
next
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice - it would sure make for a much more efficient code!